# Issue with the Hook Modifier in Curve Distortion

Tags: bezier-curves, hook-modifier

I always used the [Hook modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/deform/hooks.html) to distort the curves, but now this is happening. The "hook" simply isn't controlling the curve perfectly, it's like an armature with errors. Does anyone know what's going on?

[image: Blender 3.6 x 4.0]

Comment: Hello, could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't write in all caps in the title or body of any posts, it is the written equivalent of shouting, is [harder to read](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps#Readability) and may be [considered rude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps#Computing). Please use the [edit] button below the post to change you text into regular case.

Answer (score 5):

I think the issue is occruring because you only selected the control points and not the handles when you assigned it to a new hook object

[image]

instead, select the control point and its handles and assign them to the same object

[image]

[image]